# Input dimensions to cnn

Tags: image, classification, conv-neural-network

What is the difference between giving a 3dimension(x*y*z) input images to CNN from 4d input(number of training images*x*y*z) in an image classification?

Comment: Number of training images is typically called `batches`. This is used to tell your model how many images (batch size) you want to run in one go. This metric is typically helpful to optimize the memory usage. Due to memory constraint you cannot run everything together. Choosing the right batch size is totally dependent on the underlying hardware you are using

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the input of CNN is [batches,labels, images, channels]. You could use numpy or tensor to reshape the input.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow's `tf.nn.conv2d` op takes a 4D input tensor, `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`. The first argument here is the number of images in a batch. The other arguments are the parameters defining each image.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d